# Shell script to deny users to log in more than once

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script that looks up a list of users in a file "`/etc/user.deny`" and if a username is encountered more than once the program reports an error message an exits. So far I have:

```
while read user 
do
   #something
done < ./etc/user.deny
```

How can I compare each user name for each person. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: what is the format of `/etc/user.deny`? Probably sorting and ordering would suffice

Comment: Unfortunately this is a lab and the file is not real, but I believe the file would be laid out with just one username per line and that's it

Comment: Try `sort /tmp/test|uniq -c|sed -n 's/^[^0-9]\+[2-9]\+\(.*\)$/\1/p'`.

Comment: @alvits to do some checks on numbers is always better to use awk: `awk '$1>1 {print $2}'`

Comment: A more concise single liner would be `sort /etc/user.deny | uniq -d`. Anything printed occurs more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he wants to kill all duplicate logins

```
#!/bin/bash
#creat a sorted list
who -u | sort -k1,5 -r > userlogins.txt
#
user=""
olduser=""
# read userlist
cat userlogins.txt | while read line; do
# [0] of array is the username
# [1] is terminal
# [3] is login date
# [4] is PID
  user=($line)
#  echo ${user[0]}
#
# kill terminal if user has more than one login
  if [$olduser = ${user[0]}]; then
    echo ${user[0]} duplicate
    pkill -t ${user[1]}
  fi
# remember old user
  olduser="${user[0]}"
done
```

Unfortunately I have no possibility to test this script at the moment.

Comment: Now that you mention duplicate logins, I think the OP wants to deny subsequent logins if the user is already logged in. So maybe it will be a script executed by `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @Alexander Baltasar Hi, I tried the script but Ive error line 17: [: missing ]'` any idea what is wrong, thanks in advance. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to report when a line appears more than once, then you may want to use `awk` alone:

```
awk 'seen[$0]++ {print "seen more than once: ", $0; exit}' file
```

In the array `seen[]` we store the times every line has appeared. If one appears more than once, it triggers the `print` and `exit` statement. Otherwise, it finishes silently.

Comment: Would this work of multiple users who appear more than once or would it exits upon the first users it's seen more than once?

Comment: This exits once it finds the first duplicate. Isn't this the requirement?